# Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 8.0 - after Android Studio update

Tags: android, gradle, ionic-framework, capacitor

I updated to Android 2022.1.1 Patch 1 and now my project does not work and gives the error:

> Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it
> incompatible with Gradle 8.0

Any tips on resolving this?

For now I am looking at uninstalling and moving back to Android studio bumblebee 2021.1.1 until I have time to sort out these issues.

It is an Ionic/Capacitor project using capacitor 3.9.0

Update:
I have rolled back to bumblebee 2021.1.1 which is working fine. I will look at updating once I have more time.